# iron:router how to redirect to a url with a different domain?

Tags: redirect, meteor, request, iron-router, iron

*Question has been modified through progression*

The 'result' value from the server is a unique url (that is not my domain) that I pass back to the client (see my Meteor.call function).

**How can I direct the user to this url ?**. Using iron:router `Router.go();` does not work because it appends the url to my domain.

The method is called when a user clicks a button 'getgoodreads.'

Server.js

```
var request = Npm.require('request');
var querystring = Npm.require('querystring');

Meteor.methods({
 getGoodreads: function () {
   request.post('http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/request_token', {
            oauth: {
            consumer_key: 'someKey',
            consumer_secret: 'someSecretKey'
            }
      }, function (err, res, body)  {
        req_data = querystring.parse(body);
        result= 'http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize?' + querystring.stringify({oauth_token: req_data.oauth_token});
    });
         return result;
 } 
});
```

client.js

```
Template.profiles.events({
'click #goodreads': function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     Meteor.call('getGoodreads', function (error, result) {
       if (error) {
          console.log(error)
          } else {
console.log(result);
         Router.go(result); 
          }
      });
     }
});
```

I get this error: 
    *Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: `"http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=IBR4tGXdAgQbEsqmxve5Q."`

The correct url to redirect to is:  `http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=IWDH8EWUhn1jtrjsQA`

*

lib

```
Router.route('/profile/', {
 name: 'profile',
 waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('profile');
    },
 action: function () {
 ***maybe make the post function here?***


// this.ready() is true if all items returned from waitOn are ready
if (this.ready())
this.render('profile');
  else
this.render('Loading');
  }
});
```

*The 'result' link takes the user to the goodreads page where the user grants me access to their data by signing into their goodreads account. However, as this route is not defined in my routes, I get an error. This will be the case because every url will is unique.

Answer (score 1):

The oauth1 one is a dependency package used by other packages, specifically `accounts-twitter`. There aren't any docs for it in the conventional sense.

If you want to make your own oauth login for a service not listed on atmospherejs.com you could start out by looking at other packages that use oauth-1. I had to do this to allow bitbucket logins with my app a while ago. The source of that package is here: https://github.com/Tarang/Meteor-Accounts-Bitbucket

There are a few others too, most are nearly the same besides renaming the URLs and service names:

- Aweber: https://github.com/mpowaga/meteor-accounts-aweber
- Xero: https://github.com/axwaxw/accounts-xero

Comment: I am reading through the code and trying to break down how it is working. I understand the some of the authentication code such as passing the POST request to get a token, authenticating and being granted the access token. However, the rest I do not understand as it is specific to the service providers.
I have authenticated users with the oauth2.0 method without using any package but oauth1.0 seems very difficult to grasp.

Comment: @CodeCandy for which service are you building for?

Comment: As I am using this api call ...  https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#reviews.list  I must get the users 'id'

Comment: what is the best way to direct the user to the uri I have constructed. I manually put this into the browser console after copying it from the log and it works. So I know this is the next step.

I am using iron router. This authentication process begins by method call

Comment: @CodeCandy I had a look at this, so the user is going to log in via goodreads then call api calls? If so its just about replacing the urls to goodreads ones and renaming it to goodread in the Xero or Aweber package. If you're just doing api calls you wouldn't need the `oauth1` package and instead just sign requests using the npm module `request`

Comment: It seems I don't need the oauth package. However  I am stuck on step 2. How can I redirect the user to the variable uri as soon as the body from the innitial request is returned?

Comment: can the uri be return to the client and then put inside a Router.go() function?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out that you can do this by using the [webapp](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/webapp) meteor package.

In your server code:

```
var fakeSession = {}
url = Meteor.npmRequire('url');

WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/to-goodreads', function(req, res, next) {
  gr.requestToken(function(obj) {
    fakeSession.oauthToken = obj.oauthToken;
    fakeSession.oauthTokenSecret = obj.oauthTokenSecret;

    console.log(obj.url)
    res.writeHead(302, {
      'Location': obj.url
    });
    return res.end();
  })
})

WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/callback', function(req, res, next) {

  oauthToken = fakeSession.oauthToken;
  oauthTokenSecret = fakeSession.oauthTokenSecret;
  params = url.parse(req.url, true);
  return gr.processCallback(oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret, params.query.authorize, function(callback) {
    console.log('processed callback')
    res.write(JSON.stringify(callback));
    return res.end();
  });
})
```

Where gr is the [goodreads](https://github.com/bdickason/node-goodreads/) npm module